# How to launch bootstrap modal only if one of two options is checked followed by a button submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the standard bootstrap modal from  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

HTML code :

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the above modal works, as it pops up once the button is clicked.

But I have two radio boxes and I only want to open the modal once a user checked `accept` radio option and hits a button.

```
<form>
    <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="xx" checked>Accept</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio"  name="xx">Reject</label>
    </div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
</form>
```

the problem with the above code is the modal will popup even if user has checked `reject` choice. I don't want that to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to drop back to procedurally triggering the modal to add conditions to the display of the modal.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<form>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="xx" value=true checked>Accept</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="xx" value=false>Reject</label>
  </div>

  <!-- Drop the attributes that trigger the modal display -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg conditional-launch">Conditional Modal</button>
</form>

<script>
  // Add this in to target the button and bind to the click event
  $(".conditional-launch").click(
    function(event) {

      // Then get the currently selected radio button's value
      var value = $("input[name=xx]:checked").val();

      // Check the value to make sure you want to show the modal
      if (value === 'true') {
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
      }
    }
  );

</script>
```

Here is a jsfiddle to check it out working: https://jsfiddle.net/z7b5krse/. The code here can be copy/pasted as long as you have jQuery and Bootstrap being loaded prior to the `script` block.

Comment: Updated for Bootstrap 4.6.x:
This solution can still work, however I needed to add a slight adjustment in this case. The statement to show the modal "modal('show')" can be safely removed. Instead I replaced it with the following which seemed to work in my case -- when on click function returns false, bootstrap won't show the modal which is the desired behavior.

So in my on click function I updated the logic as follows:
    showCondition = ...
  // Define condition to show modal (true or false)
  return showCondition;